# Axis labelling not possible using matplotlib with LateX

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I have installed LateX(TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) kpathsea version 6.1.1) on Ubuntu 14.04LTS, ghostscript(9.10) and dvipng(1.14) according to the example in the matplotlib documentation ([usetex](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html)). If I comment out the label properties of the plot everything works fine, but when not, either they do not show up or it is raising an error (see in the code snippet below). How can I handle axis labelling with latex properly? Do I need a further package?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Example data
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0 + 0.01, 0.01)
s = np.cos(4 * np.pi * t) + 2

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7.5))
plt.xlabel(r'testx') # not showing up
plt.ylabel(r'testy',fontsize=16) #ValueError: Can only output finite numbers in PDF
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.title(r"\TeX\ is Number "
         r"$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-e^{i\pi}}{2^n}$!",
          fontsize=16, color='gray')
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)
plt.grid()
plt.savefig('tex_demo.pdf')
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance and best regards, clax

Beneath are both tracebacks, one with savefig and one with show:

savefig:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    plt.savefig('tex_demo.pdf')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 561, in savefig
    return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1421, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2220, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1952, in print_pdf
    return pdf.print_pdf(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2352, in print_pdf
    self.figure.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1105, in draw
    self.label.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/text.py", line 594, in draw
    self._fontproperties, angle, mtext=self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 1782, in draw_tex
    self._setup_textpos(curx, cury, angle, oldx, oldy)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 1649, in _setup_textpos
    x,        y,         Op.textmatrix)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 548, in output
    self.write(fill(map(pdfRepr, data)))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 144, in pdfRepr
    raise ValueError("Can only output finite numbers in PDF")
ValueError: Can only output finite numbers in PDF
```

show:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 276, in resize
    self.show()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 348, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1105, in draw
    self.label.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/text.py", line 594, in draw
    self._fontproperties, angle, mtext=self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 241, in draw_tex
    self._renderer.draw_text_image(Z, x, y, angle, gc)
OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

Comment: Can you please paste in the full tracebacks?

Comment: your example works fine for me.

Comment: now I was able to restrict the source of the problem: it worked with executing it as root and not as a normal user. Is there any environment variable causing this or do I have to set file permissions?

Comment: Same as wsj, working well on my laptop. I don't know where your infinity is coming from; did you check the generated values? I can't help you about the possible env variable, but can you tell us your versions of  `numpy` and `matplotlib`? Also my [backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) is `"Qt5Agg"` while yours seem to be `"TkAgg"`, so maybe you should try another one to see whether it is the source of the problem...

Comment: thank you for commenting, I tried to switch all file permissions of matplotlib. Now it is running with a user without any errors occurring like mentioned above. But still there is a strange behaviour executing it as a user. Some parts of the plot (e.g. left or lower part) are cut off. I am using Python 2.7.6 and matplotlib 1.3.1.